# perl regex to extract table names from stored procedure

Tags: regex, perl

I need to extract the list of table names from the stored procedure for example the SP may contain one or more SQLs.

```
select
t.ticket, t.subsid, null, null
from
    Trans t
where
    subsid = @subsid

select *
from
   Trans t, Cpty c, Book b
where
t.ticket            =  c.ticket
```

Now i need to extract Trans , Cpty and Book as table names. The sqls are in multi line how to extract theses information in perl regex.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict; use warnings;
open my $f, "<", 'input' or die("$!");
my %tables;
while (<$f>) {
    next if !/\bfrom\b/;
    while (<$f>) {
        $tables{$_} = 1 for map { (split)[0] } split(/,/);
        last if !/,\s*$/
    }   
}
close $f; 
print join(",", keys %tables), "\n";
```

*Produces:*

```
Book,Cpty,Trans
```